# How to process 20GB of data file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a requirement to get a unique JSON record depending on certain conditions from 20GB of data present in a file(depending on queryId). Each line in the file is a JSON record.
EX :

`{"sessionID":"xyz","appID":"abc","tenantID":"123","realmId":"buyer_2021","topology":"top456","queryId":"12346278","signalType":"USER_QUERY_RESULTS",XYZ content.....}`

Comment: What is format of your file? Did you consider using apache hive? Creating hive table on your file and simply query to filter your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> Each line in the file is a JSON record.

Start with Spark. You don't need Hadoop for only 20 GB of data

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("file.json")
```

With that, you can select/filter/groupBy, etc the query ID field.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html